# Need help resolving the following error: ChromeDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: selenium, runtime-error, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently facing an error while trying to run my selenium scripts on latest version of  Selenium standalone-server v3.0.1. The error is as follows :-

org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

The chromedriver version is 2.25 & the chrome browser version I have is  54.0.2840.90 (64-bit). Please can you tell me if anyone has faced such an issue? And how do u resolve it?

Comment: Once again download the same chrome driver and specify the latest chrome drivers path

Comment: Please check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi